# Nan When using Bhaskara's formula

Tags: c++

I am making a simple program using Bhaskara's formula and I get the titled error; by the way, I am using Dev-C++

Here goes the code:

```
#include<iostream>

#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   

    float a, b, c, resultado1 = 0, resultado2 = 0;
    
    cout<<"Digite el valor de la variable a: "; cin>>a;
    cout<<"Digite el valor de la variable b: "; cin>>b;
    cout<<"Digite el valor de la variable c: "; cin>>c;
    
    // /*operacion de segundo grado con "-b+" */
    resultado1 = (-b+sqrt(pow(b,2)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
    // /*operacion de segundo grado con "-b-" */
    resultado2 = (-b-sqrt(pow(b,2)-4*a*c))/(2*a);   
    
    cout<<"\nEl resultado numero uno es: "<<resultado1<<endl;
    cout<<"El resultado numero dos es: "<<resultado2<<endl;
        
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On what inputs? Not every quadratic equation has a solution (in real numbers).

Comment: maybe `a` was 0.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `4ac > b**2`?

Comment: Breakout the parts in into temporaries and see what the intermediate values are in your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAN occurs when you try to calculate something invalid like divide by 0 or sqrt() of negative value, so, just check this possibility before calculate.

https://godbolt.org/z/1Ks1xd

Comment: According to Compiler Explorer:
b^2 [100] must be greater than 4*a*c [660]
So it's something I have to take into account when executing the file and input data.